# System app : can't execute commands (Permission denied)

Tags: android, command-line, adb, iptables

I have a system app (in the /system/app folder and also signed with the system signature) and I would like to execute some commands.

It works well with adb and superuser rights, but everytime I get a "Permission denied" when I make the call from my application.

This is the kind of command I'm doing :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iptables --flush");
```

Do you know why I have this error ? And how to correct it ?

Thanks !

Comment: why won't you check the output of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/id");`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for a SU permissions first from the system.
I would suggest you to use [roottools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/):

> RootTools provides rooted developers a standardized set of tools for
>   use in the development of rooted applications. In the end, we will
>   accomplish this by providing developers with robust, easy-to-use
>   libraries that will drastically improve development times as well as
>   promote code reuse. This project is open to any proven developer that
>   feels they have something to contribute. By pitching in together we
>   can streamline our own processes, improve the effectiveness of our
>   apps, learn new techniques, and provide a better experience for our
>   users.

**EDIT**: Can you please describe the process of signing your APK with the system certificates? Have you edited your AndroidManifest.xml as well?